# acpi bios error(bug) : failure creating [\/_SB.PCIO.XHC.RHUB.SS09 Ae_AALREADY_EXISTS(20181213/dswload2-324)

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, nvidia, acpi

[image with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3L4M.jpg)

i bought a new laptop and I'm trying to install ubuntu 18.04. when i press "install ubuntu" some errors occur and I don't know how to solve them. I installed the latest BIOS update on my laptop, but I think that there is a compatibility problem with the graphic card. What can I do? Thank you for your support!

Comment: Did you verify your ISO download was flawless? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and then write to media perfect https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck   If you can boot 'live' (try ubuntu), then providing details of your video hardware may help (`sudo lshw -C video` or list-hardware of class video).  Which 18.04 did you try to install?

Comment: i downloaded .iso file from the official site and also i followed the steps as i have done it in the past with my former laptop. I tried to instal 18.04.3 LTS